# How to nest suffix file names like "texts-fr.json" to "texts.json" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-organization

I have a folder with i18n texts with files like this: `texts.json` and its translations: `texts-en.json`, `texts-fr.json` etc.

I am trying to use [`fileSuffixToExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022#the-filesuffixtoextension-provider) to nest all other files under `texts.json` but it does not work. Apparently wildcard is not supported. Is it possible?

```json
      "fileSuffixToExtension": {
        "add": {
            "-*.json": [
                ".json"
            ]
        }
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now apparently `fileSuffixToExtension` does not support wildcard because even the JSON schema recognize that:

[image]

So I have to manually add one entry for each language code (using some quick JS code to auto generate them).

[image]

```json
      "fileSuffixToExtension": {
        "add": {
            "-vsdoc.js": [
                ".js"
            ],
            "-ar.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-bg.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ca.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-cs.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-da.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-de.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-el.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-en.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-es.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-et.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-fa.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-fi.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-fr.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-he.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-hi.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-hr.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-hu.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-id.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-is.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-it.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ja.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ko.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-lt.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-lv.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ms.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-nl.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-no.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-pl.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-pt.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ro.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ru.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-sk.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-sl.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-sr.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-sv.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-th.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-tl.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-tr.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-uk.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-ur.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-vi.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-zh-CN.json": [
                ".json"
            ],
            "-zh-TW.json": [
                ".json"
            ]
        }
      },
```

I have submitted a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-wildcard-for-fileSuffixToExtension/10506703)